# Matlab: Find pattern in an image given a skeletonized template

Tags: matlab, template-matching

I am stuck at a current project:
I have an input picture showing the ground with some shapes on it. I have to find a specific shape with a given template.

I have to use distance transformation into skeletonization. My question now is: How can I compare two skeletons? As far as I noticed and have been told, the most methods from the Image Processing Toolbox to match templates don't work, since they are not scale-invariant and rotation invariant.
Also some skeletons are really showing the shapes, others are just one or two short lines, with which I couldn't identify the shapes, if I didn't know what they should be.

I've used edge detection, and region growing on the input so there are only interessting shapes left.
On the template I used distance transformation and skeletonization.

Really looking forward to some tips.
Greetings :)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into convolutions?

Basically move your template over your image and see if there is a match, and where.
The max value of your array [x,y] is the location of your object in the image.

[Matlab has a built-in 2D convolution function for this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)

Comment: This wouldn't be scale- or rotation-invariant.

Comment: Fast radial symmetry transform is also an option, or Hough Transform to name some and even radon transformations. Dot the better answers we need some more input from the TO